# Printing stairs with men using stars

Tags: java

I am supposed to complete the method

```
public static void printStairs(int numMen) {

}
```

which prints

```
                  o  ******
                 /|\ *    *
                 / \ *    *
             o  ******    *
            /|\ *         *
            / \ *         *
        o  ******         *
       /|\ *              *          
       / \ *              *          
      *********************
```

I got

```
   public static void printStairs(int numMen) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numMen; i++) {
     String space = "";
     String space2="";
     for (int j = numMen - i; j > 1; j--) {
        space += "     ";
     }
     for (int j = 2; j <=numMen-i; j++) {
        space2 += "     ";
     }

     System.out.println(space + "  o  ******"+space2+"*");
     System.out.println(space + " /|\\ *    "+space2+"*");
     System.out.println(space + " / \\ *    "+space2+"*");


  }
   for(int i=0; i<=5*numMen+6; i++){

   System.out.print("*");
   }  

      }
```

Which gives

```
                  o  ******       *
                 /|\ *          *
                 / \ *          *
             o  ******   * 
            /|\ *      *   
            / \ *      *
        o  *******        
       /|\ *    *          
       / \ *    *         
      ***********
```

Instead of the image I want.

I don't understand why this does not work, as I just reversed the code for the spaces in the left of the stairs and concatenated that to the right of the stairs.

Anyone knows how to incorporate the vertical line into the code and create the image intended?

Comment: please don't edit the question once you posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
    public static void  printMan(int numMen) {

        for (int i = 0; i < numMen; i++) {
            String space ="" ,space2 ="";
            for(int j = numMen-i; j>1; j--) { 
                    space += "       ";
            }
            for(int k = 0; k<i ; k++) { 
                space2 += "       ";
             }

             System.out.println(space +" o  *****" + space2 + "*");
             System.out.println(space + "/|\\ *    "+ space2 + "*");
             System.out.println(space + "/ \\ *    "+ space2 + "*");             
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (numMen *10)-((numMen-1) *3); i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! so far the most useful !

Comment: Any idea how to get the vertical line on the left? I was thinking of creating another for loop for the spaces on the right side of the stairs but it doesn't work ^^;

Comment: ohh i see, please see revised.

Answer (score 2):

It should be conceptually easier to loop over squares of several positions:

```
public static void printStairs(int numMen)
{
    String[] manLines = {
             " o  *****",
             "/|\ *    ",
             "/ \ *    "
    };
    final int rows = manLines.length;

    for (int y = 0; y < numMen; ++y) {
        for (int yrow = 0; yrow < rows; ++yrow) { // rows per man

            for (int x = 0; x < y; ++x) {
                System.out.print("    ");
            }
            System.out.print(manLines[yrow]);
            for (int x = y; x < numMen; ++x) {
                System.out.print("    ");
            }
            System.out.println("*");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you made a typing mistake on the third for loop. It says <y without anything to compare with :). Thanks for the hint! I will try to create the code using your method!

Comment: I hesitated to give so much code, but the most important hint, is to introduce notions like "squares" to iterate over. Looping over numMen is easier than numMen*3 for the following code. _By the way, this code is not all the work._

Answer (score 1):

Using an character arrays makes it easier. For what it's worth...

```
  private static final char[][] figure = new char[][] { "  o  ******".toCharArray(), 
                                                        " /|\\ *".toCharArray(), 
                                                        " / \\ *".toCharArray()};
  private static void printStairs(int numMen)
  {
    int stairs = numMen + 1;
    int width = (stairs * 5) + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numMen; i++)
    {
      for (char[] part : figure)
      {
        char[] line = newLine(width, ' ');
        // start at least the 11 back from the end - back another 5 for each step
        System.arraycopy(part, 0, line, width - 11 - i * 5, part.length);
        System.out.println(line);

      }
    }
    System.out.println(newLine(width, '*'));
  }

  private static char[] newLine(int width, char fill)
  {
    char[] line = new char[width];
    Arrays.fill(line, fill);
    line[width - 1] = '*';
    return line;
  }
```